# Any workaround for this method without convert snapshotChanges() into promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

**I want to return cartIdFire but it returns undefined because snapshot method is return observable**
so, there is any workaround for returning cartIdFire without convert snapshot method into promise  ?

```
private async getServer() 
{
   this.db.list('/shopping-carts/').snapshotChanges()
   .subscribe(x => this.cartIdFire = x);
   return cartIdFire;
 }
```

```
private async getOrCreateCartId() //to create a cartid or acceess the cartid
  
  {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId'); //to create a cartid or acceess 
    if(cartId) 
    {
      return cartId;
    }
     this.id = await this.getServer();
     console.log(this.id);
     console.log(this.cartIdFire); //it gives undefined
    if(this.cartIdFire)
    {
       localStorage.setItem('cartId' ,result.key);
       return this.cartIdFire;
    } 
      let result =  await this.create(); 
      localStorage.setItem('cartId' ,result.key);
      return  result.key;
  }
```

so i can't return subscriber from getServer() method. Because i have to save
the cartFireId in the local storage.

Comment: Just don’t subscribe here, only return the observable to the caller. Then you can do getServer().subscribe

Comment: this is'nt working because after getserver() i have save that id into localstorage , so if i subscribe it there then the cartIdFire have the undefinned value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, `await this.getServer()` will not work, it will not wait to be solved, it only works in Promise, not in Observable, where it is solved within the subscribe

A simple solution would be, in the `getServer()` method to convert the Observable to Promise, using `toPromise()` and returning this value

```
private async getServer() 
{
   return this.db.list('/shopping-carts/').snapshotChanges().toPromise()
}
```

And get the `cartIdFire` in the `getOrCreateCartId()` method

```
this.cardIdFire = await this.getServer()
```

Comment: toPromise() is works fine with pipe(take(1)).here `return this.db.list('/shopping-carts/').snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();` is working.Because toPromise is resolved when Observable resolved.